# How do I create low poly cliffs?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, procedural

I'm attempting to recreate the cliffs on this image and I want to know how to create something procedural with the style of the image showcasing the example cliffs

[image: Low poly cliff]

[image: Low poly cliff]

I've attempted geo nodes but it was not where I wanted it to be.

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell us more about it? What part of this scenery do you want to procedurally design and in what form? Just the front of the cliffs? Please try to make your question as precise as possible, because this topic seems to be very extensive.

Comment: @quellenform Hey yea so those cliffs you see towards the front but essentially I want to create procedural cliffs like the ones in the second photo

Comment: OK, thank you, please tell us a little more about it. The task leaves too much room for maneuver. Are you concerned with a straight line front, or does it follow a specific shape. Can you show us what you have done so far or where exactly you are hanging? Maybe it would be good if you share a concrete example as a blend file.

Comment: @quellenform Yea so I was able to achieve this https://streamable.com/zqg8g6

And im not sure how to upload a blender filer on here

Comment: @quellenform i got it up and edited it on the post